# Почему angular обновляет страницу?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

При переходе по url, angular отображает нужный шаблон, но при этом обновляет всю страницу

```html
<a class="btn btn-mini animation" ng-click="locateTo($event, data)">
    <!--<i style="margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 2px" class="fa fa-caret-right"
        ng-hide="data.hasChilds"></i>-->
    <span>{{data.title}}</span>
</a>
```

```js
$scope.locateTo = function (event, data) {
    if(!data.select) {
        data.select = true;

        if($state.current.name === "graphics" && data.type !== 90) {

            $state.go("counters", {
                counterName: "readings",
                placetype: data.type,
                placeid: data.id
            });

        } else {

            $state.go($state.current.name, {
                placetype: data.type,
                placeid: data.id
            });
        }
    }

    // $location.path(getCurrentTab + '/' + id);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

```
$event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: и как он тут может помочь? у `a` даже `href` нет

Comment: @Grundy,подозреваю, что оно добавляется..

Answer (score 0):

По привычке всегда выставляю в тегах ссылки `href` без значения, как-то так:

```
<a href ng-click="foobar()">link text</a>
```

Может поможет.

Comment: Что-то сомнительно, что это поможет.